# What should I alternatively call that URL of /books-more/ ? (SEO)

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

I have an Area on a Website that we're relaunching that will include Books & Other Products (like DVD's, Calendars ect.). It's the website of a bestselling author, so most of the people will look and know him for his books. That's why were going to call the Overview-Page (every product has it's own sub-page) "Books & More".

You can't buy the Single "Products" on the Website, they just include a Link to amazon.

**Now the problem that I'm having is the URL from SEO-Perspective:**

**What I have now is:**

Books & More (Overview Page): /books-more/
Single-Product: /books-more/product-name/

**Alternative 1**

I'm thinking, that the "more" in the URL is an empty word, making the URL-unnessecary longer. but only having /books/ in the url would not be logically correct (for instance: /books/this-is-a-dvd/)

**Alternative 2**

Making the URL /products/ while keeping the Page name, Menu Item and all references to that page as "Books & More". Here I see a problem with sending mixed signals to Google. (Also, the main Keyword for that page will be "*name* + text".

**What do you think?**

I don't see any other or better alternative. What do you think is the right way to handle that SEO-Wise?

Comment: "and more" is almost always a bad idea. All websites have more than can fit in a very short description. Pretty much every section of every web page isn't limited to exactly what fits in a couple word title.is attempting to use it when building or describing your web page because you want your website to appear expansive and not have narrow titles.  However users won't find it useful. How much more does it include? Doesn't include plays? How about cars? It really provides no useful information to users.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought...

Since the website is for "a bestselling author" who appears to have several books, shouldn't "books" be the primary focus and have their own section?

So, basically, "alternative 1" + "alternative 2" = "alternative 3"...

- `/books/` - Overview page for books
- `/books/title-of-book` - page for book
- `/products/` or `/other-products`? - Overview page for other (non-book) items.
- `/other-products/this-is-a-dvd` - page for DVD.